# Publish web site and wcf service to azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, azure, web-deployment

I have one solution in VS, which holds a lightweight MVC web site, and a WCF service, that is consumed by that site, that implements some buisness logic.

In my local deployment I have web site at port 3333 and service at port 4444 in iis.

I would like to have a deployment in azure, that would be as close as possible to my local deployment, to get rid of all the problems like specifying wcf service address separately for local tests and azure deployments (so that web site on port 3333 could actually see wcf service on localhost:4444, when running in azure).

I would be grateful for any info regarding how to achieve this, thanks in advance. (In case this is impossible, please, tell me, what is the closest setup?)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that but only if you manually edit the WebRode config, there you can define the structure that the target deployment will have (from an IIS point of view) and you can create VirtualDirectories and map them to the folders that correspond to your projects as they will be on the deployment machine.

---

This should be all the info you need to get this done: http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/02/running-multiple-websites-in-a-windows-azure-web-role/